# Can not open NavigationDrawer from Toolbar Menu Items android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

Hi I try to use this tutorial to make a NavigationDrawer in android but I wan't to change the way that Drawer is open. the tutorial is this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

in this tutorial the Drawer open with default home button in toolbar I want to open it with menu item.

this is my main code:

```
public class First_page extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener  {

    Button go_layout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_page);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.page_logo_2);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        go_layout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_to_page);

        go_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(First_page.this, Full_page.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.right_btn) {


            Toast.makeText(First_page.this, "Right_btn clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
            drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
            drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I handle opening and closing of the NavigationDrawer.  Just call handleNavDrawer() where ever you want to open or close it.

**Handling open and close of the drawer**

```
public void handleNavDrawer() {
    if (mNavigationDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mNavigationDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        mNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

**Working Example**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mNavigationDrawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracker);
        mNavigationDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_search) { 
            handleNavDrawer();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void handleNavDrawer() {
        if (mNavigationDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mNavigationDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** with your example

```
public class First_page extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener  {

    Button go_layout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    private DrawerLayout mNavigationDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_page);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.page_logo_2);

        go_layout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_to_page);
        go_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(First_page.this, Full_page.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        mNavigationDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, mNavigationDrawer, toolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.right_btn) {
            Toast.makeText(First_page.this, "Right_btn clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handleNavDrawer();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    // Close the Nav Drawer
    // handleNavDrawer();
    }

    public void handleNavDrawer() {
        if (mNavigationDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mNavigationDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but as I say, I'm use the tutorial I post my activity code.actually the tutorial not use DrawerLayout. I post my code.

Comment: It is using DrawerLayout. You just need to call DrawerLayout within the onCreate and put what I have added.  I suggest not using the example you are using doing. I will update my answer with what you have but look into using NavigationView.

Comment: Just updated my answer, calling the DrawerLayout within the onCreate.

Comment: Work Perfect. Many Thanks.

Comment: No Problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My method is a onClick called  "btnClickSideBar" . You can call it whatever you want. 
When you give a click it will check if the Drawer is Open or Close. If it is Open our method it will Close and If it is Close the Drawer will Open.

```
public void btnClickSideBar(View view) {

                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerContainer)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerContainer);
                }
            }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.